# Saving dozens of 2D levels in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, serialization, game-engine, saving-data

I need to save dozens levels of my 2D platformer game for smartphone in Unity3D.
Making scene for every level is not acceptable because I also creating level editor for community. Saving into database (SQLite) is acceptable but not wanted if there are other options. Are they?

Comment: What is a `level` for you? I you just need a certain set of information why not just use a custom class `LevelInformation` containing whatever you need to build your levels (the same way you would probably do with an SQL database?)?

Comment: @derHugo is right; moreover, assuming that the community levels are (by definition) shared over the Internet, they cannot be actual Unity scenes, because scenes need to be explicitly added to the build of the application. You must found a format (eg: xml) that can be read from the application in order to generate the scene elements on-the-fly starting from a "standard" empty scene. Hope this helps.

Comment: i've seen this done quite efficiently with XML. depends on the levels and what they contain though...

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー Well, scenes CAN be loaded via asset bundles, but you need to download and install Unity in order to *create* asset bundles.

Comment: @Vanethrane Levels will be items and coordinates. Best will be if I am able to serialize whole gameobject to not be forced to use structured gameobjects